# BMI calculator bug

Tags: c++, math

I'm trying to do a basic BMI calculator, and it works fine when I do the metric side of it, however, the imperial side returns a wrong answer.

```
cout << "What is your weight? ";
cin >> weight;

cout << "What is your height in either inches or meters? ";
cin >> height;

cout << "Is that metric or imperial? Type 1 for metric, or 0 for imperial ";
cin >> unit;

if (unit = 1) 
answer = weight / (height * height);
if (unit = 0)
answer = (weight * 703) / (height * height);
cout << "Your BMI is " << answer << endl;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

I thought the equation for BMI for imperial, according to Wikipedia was

Weight(in pounds) * 703 / (height in inches squared)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use == for testing equality not =

Answer (score 1):

You are using the assignment operator "=" in your if statements, both of which will ALWAYS return true, because you ARE able to assign the value of "0" or "1" to unit.

To test for equality you must use "==".

This should fix this problem! (: